# How to cancel specific request from all pending request

Tags: ionic3, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In my Ionic web app,

> For browser

I want to implement a cancel download feature and currently, users can download multiple files at the same time so I want to cancel specific download HTTP request.

This is what I currently have.

```
@Effect()
public fileDownloadAction$: Observable<Action> = this.action$
    .ofType(FileDownloadActionTypes.FILE_DOWNLOAD_REQUESTED)
    .map(this.toPayload)
    .mergeMap(payload => (this.downloadService.downloadFile(payload))
        .concatMap((res: any) => {                       
            return Observable.from([
                new FileDownloadCompleted(downloadSuccess)
            ]);
        })
    )
```

But I don't have a clue how to do this inside an effect. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you considered something like `downloadService.downloadFile(payload).pipe(takeUntil(stopDownload(payload)))`, where `stopDownload` will generate an observable that will emit when the file should stop downloading.

Comment: yes, I tried but it stops all file download requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the specific question is but you can use `exhaustMap` or `switchMap` (instead of `mergeMap`) to cancel new or pending requests.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)
I tried `exhaustMap` but it allows 1 download request at a time and `switchMap` cancel all ongoing download request and allow only 1 download request at a time

so in order to allow multiple file download request i have used `mergeMap`.

My question is i want to cancel specific file download request not all

Comment: I don't have a lot of time currently, but I think you will have to use groupBy on the payload and then use the takeUntil that Andrei mentioned inside the grouped requests. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsr4ArAsOL4 (a talk from mike and sam about the groupby operator)

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time digging into RxJS I did it without changing effect Here is mess magic.

```
public download (endpoint: string, body: any = {}, uniqueKey: string) {

let req = new HttpRequest('POST', endpoint, body, { 
  responseType: 'blob',
  reportProgress: true, 
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  })
});

return new Observable(observable => {
  let downloadRequest = this.http.request(req).subscribe(results => {
      observable.next(results);
      if(results['type'] == 4) {
       //Complete Observable once download success
        observable.complete();
      }
  });
  allDownloadReq[uniqueKey] = downloadRequest;
});
}
```

I have pushed each download subscriber in an array and canceled it with **uniqeKey**

```
public cancelDownload (key) {
  if(allDownloadReq[key]) {
    allDownloadReq[key].unsubscribe()
    return true;
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

**Suggestions have still welcome**

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: also, axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) works great!